# Python: modul not found after Anaconda installation

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I've successfully installed Python 2.7 and Anaconda but when i try to import a library i get always this error:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I've set up the `PYTHONHOME` to `C:\Python27` and `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\Python27\Lib`.

**EDIT : content of PATH**

In my $PATH variable i have `C:\Users\Mattia\Anaconda2`, `C:\Users\Mattia\Anaconda2\Scripts` and `C:\Users\Mattia\Anaconda2\Library\bin`.

Do i have to set any other env veriables?

Comment: What is in your $PATH variable? (Try "echo $PATH")

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Did you try it without modifying `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem because now i see the Anaconda version in the python prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you should not have either `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` set.  They are both pointing to a non-Continuum version of Anaconda, I believe.  Anaconda will install (by default) into a directory called `Anaconda`, either at `C:\Anaconda` or at `C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda` (IIRC).  It is generally recommended that you should not ever set `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME`, except as a last resort, exactly because of these kinds of problems.

You can see which Python interpreter you're running by doing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
```

And then you can see what directories are ending up in your Python library path (where `import` statements will look for packages, such as `scipy` and `numpy`) by doing one of the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

or the more readable version:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...    print p
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I printed the path, and I see it includes the directory the module is installed in yet it says Module not found!

Comment: This helped, I needed to do `unset PYTHONPATH` then everything worked fine for me using the conda base environment. I tried to run a custom installed python module.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Mr.F the error was given by the presence of the `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`. Deleting them i was able to use the Anaconda version of python.

Comment: Ahh! This took me FOREVER. I had to delete `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH` from my `~/.bash_profile` (for osx)

Answer (score 2):

If you have module not found error, you may need to launch python from anaconda terminal using "python" instead of the shortened "py". I had my module installed properly, but spent forever trying to fix it because of this. Apparently py does not launch the anaconda activated or anaconda base environment, but launches another version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Use
$ conda install package_name instead

Comment: This problem still persist even if you use conda install

Answer (score 0):

When using anaconda environment other than base, this issue is mostly due to kernel.
See this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJ05omgQCMw) that best explains it

The solution is in the video.
You can also check the [Ipython documentation here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) for more details.

Quick solution:

- Make user that you identify the various python installations on your machine and that you are the intended one in anaconda. You can use `which -a python`. You can also check your path to ensure there aren't various python bin folders in the path.
- Use `jupyter kernelspec list` to identify the various kernels in anaconda.
- Preferably use different kernels for different environment.
- In my case, I activated the new enviroment using `conda active myenv`, then install a kernel for myenv using `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"`
- Note that the python executable should be the right one - preferable from `<ANACONDA_HOME>/bin/`

This solved the issue for me.
Credit to the links attached to this post.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJ05omgQCMw
- https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html