# conda kernels and conda modules not found in jupyter notebooks when added, but otherwise existant?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

There are many questions like this (e.g. [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook), [Python: modul not found after Anaconda installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449725/python-modul-not-found-after-anaconda-installation), https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271137/importing-anaconda-libraries-not-working). I have tried their solutions but to no avail.

In short, I have conda installed. I have installed `jupyterlabs` and `nb_conda_kernels` in my base environment. When I create a new conda env via a file, the environment is not listed in jupyter automatically. I can add it via

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <env-name>
```

but then after I restart jupyter and switch kernels, when I try to import a python module from it, it says module not found.

What do I need to do to fix this? I do not want to add jupyterlabs to every env.

NOTE:

- when activating the env in the terminal the path is correct, e.g.  `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/<env-name>/bin`
- when using the env in the terminal, the pack is there.
- when using the kernel in Jupyter, the module is not there.

Comment: You don't mention installing `ipykernel` in the new environment - that must be done for the `nb_conda_kernels` package to auto-register the kernel. You should not have to manually register and what is possibly happening is you are registering some other Python, but just giving it a name that matches the environment.

Comment: Could you add what `import sys; print(sys.path)` shows in a notebook running a kernel of interest?